# Looking for a control to repeat a certain template

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, controls

Greetings,

I'm looking for a way in Silverlight to have a control which repeats a template for each item bound to it.

I'll try to explain a bit better.

http://img51.imageshack.us/i/naamloosmb.png/

in the screenshot you see a few of the lessons available.

The list contains: "Zumba, Squash, Spinning, Spinning Marathon, Personal Trainer (PT) Sessies" etc
Each item has a description, a picture and a button to go to the page for the corrosponding lesson.

Does anyone know if there is a control available which allows me to achieve this?

If not, how should I start to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a listbox and an itemtemplate?

Here is a great tutorial: http://backissues.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=112091&page=1

Basically you can use a `Setter` to define an item template (remember in Silverlight/WPF an item's content can be any object) with a layout inside.

E.g.

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
   <Setter.Value>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30"
                     Margin="2"
                     Fill="{Binding Logo}" />
              <Label Content="{Binding Name}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     FontSize="14" />
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Producing:

[image]

Comment: (+1 JD)  Or you can use the ItemsControl if you don't want any selection logic, which works essentially like a Repeater control.